# Javascript Color button

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Problem:
I want to Change `<p>` color on a click, that changes back if i click the button again. I tried for several hours and have no clue how to do that. Here is the code

```
<div class="items">
   <div>
    <button onclick="colorChange()"></button>
   </div>
  <p>
   ORT: TARDES
   <br>
   BERUF: Der Doktor   
  </p>
</div>
```

I don't have any good Javascript knowledge.
Thanks for the Answers! I am still new to JS.

EDIT: I tried this. Its not completed or functioning at all

```
function colorChange(){
    i = 0
    cObject = document.querySelector('.maincontainer>.container>.items>p');
    console.log(cObject.childNodes);
    cObject.style.color = "red";
    if (cObject.sryle.color == "red"){
        alter(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, even if you JS tries did not worked, could you please still add them. It might help us help you.

Comment: There's a typo: `sryle`. Also, you're setting the color to "red", then check the color in the next line. How is it ever going to be anything other than "red"? And where is `alter()`?

Comment: As i mentioned its not working at all or complete, thats why iam asking for a alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use inline styles. Instead, define and toggle a CSS class that affects the color. Example:

```js
const colorChangeBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.colorChangeBtn'); // get a NodeList of all color change buttons

for (const btn of colorChangeBtns) { // iterate over the list
  btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => { // when a button is clicked
    event // event is implicitly passed to the handler function
      .target // event.target is the element on which the event occurred (the button)
      .closest('.items') // starting from the button, find the closest element with .items
      .querySelector('p') // and inside that, find the first p element
      .classList.toggle('red'); // and on its list of CSS classes, toggle this class name
  })
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div>
    <button class="colorChangeBtn">Change color</button>
  </div>
  <p>
    ORT: TARDES
    <br> BERUF: Der Doktor
  </p>
</div>

<div class="items">
  <div>
    <button class="colorChangeBtn">Change color</button>
  </div>
  <p>
    ORT: TARDES
    <br> BERUF: Der Doktor
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with values. Initialize the color with red, for the first click then check if your value it's red or black:

```js
function colorChange() {

  // let cObject = document.querySelector('.maincontainer>.container>.items>p');
  let cObject = document.querySelector('.items>p');
  
  cObject.style.color = "red"
  
 if (cObject.value == "black") {
    cObject.value = "red";
    cObject.style.color = "red"
  } else {
    cObject.value = "black";
    cObject.style.color = "black"
  }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div>
    <button onclick="colorChange()" value="black"> change color</button>
  </div>
  <p>
    ORT: TARDES
    <br> BERUF: Der Doktor
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get that using this code

```js
window.flag=false;
function changeColor(){
 var toChange= document.getElementById("red");
    window.flag=!window.flag;
    if(window.flag){
       toChange.style.color="red";
    }else{
       toChange.style.color="black";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onClick="changeColor()">Change color</button>
<p id="red"> ORT: TARDES<br>BERUF: Der Doktor  </p>
```